# Loading large images without OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, android-image

I have a 5000 x 4000 px image which I want to draw onto a canvas.

First I tried to load it from resources.
I put it in `/res/drawable`.

I used the following method:

```
InputStream input = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.huge_image);
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(input, "image");
d.setBounds(...);
d.draw(canvas);
```

It worked like a charm.

In this case the `InputStream` is an `AssetManager.AssetInputStream`.

So now I want to load it from the sdcard.

Here's what I tried to do:

```
File f = new File(path);
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(f);
InputStream input = mContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(input, "image");
```

In this case the `InputStream` is a `FileInputStream` and I got an `OutOfMemoryError` when creating the `Drawable`.

So I'm wondering:

Is there a way to load the image without getting that error? Or is there a way to convert a `FileInputStream` to an `AssetInputStream` ?

Note:

I don't want to resize the image because I'm implementing zoom/pan functionality.
Please don't tell me to read [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html).

You can check out the full class [here](https://github.com/BenitoBertoli/ZoomImageView/blob/master/src/com/benitobertoli/largeimagezoom/ZoomImageView.java). The error occurs when using `setImageUri()`.

Here's my Error Log:

```
08-13 11:57:54.180: E/AndroidRuntime(23763): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-13 11:57:54.180: E/AndroidRuntime(23763): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
08-13 11:57:54.180: E/AndroidRuntime(23763):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
08-13 11:57:54.180: E/AndroidRuntime(23763):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:468)
08-13 11:57:54.180: E/AndroidRuntime(23763):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:332)
08-13 11:57:54.180: E/AndroidRuntime(23763):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
08-13 11:57:54.180: E/AndroidRuntime(23763):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromStream(Drawable.java:657)
08-13 11:57:54.180: E/AndroidRuntime(23763):    at com.benitobertoli.largeimagezoom.ZoomImageView.setDrawablefromUri(ZoomImageView.java:187)
08-13 11:57:54.180: E/AndroidRuntime(23763):    at com.benitobertoli.largeimagezoom.ZoomImageView.setImageUri(ZoomImageView.java:588)
08-13 11:57:54.180: E/AndroidRuntime(23763):    at com.benitobertoli.largeimagezoom.TestActivity.onKeyDown(TestActivity.java:30)
08-13 11:57:54.180: E/AndroidRuntime(23763):    at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:1257)
08-13 11:57:54.180: E/AndroidRuntime(23763):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2075)
08-13 11:57:54.180: E/AndroidRuntime(23763):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1673)
08-13 11:57:54.180: E/AndroidRuntime(23763):    at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventToViewHierarchy(ViewRoot.java:2493)
08-13 11:57:54.180: E/AndroidRuntime(23763):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRoot.java:2463)
08-13 11:57:54.180: E/AndroidRuntime(23763):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1752)
08-13 11:57:54.180: E/AndroidRuntime(23763):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-13 11:57:54.180: E/AndroidRuntime(23763):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
08-13 11:57:54.180: E/AndroidRuntime(23763):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
08-13 11:57:54.180: E/AndroidRuntime(23763):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-13 11:57:54.180: E/AndroidRuntime(23763):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-13 11:57:54.180: E/AndroidRuntime(23763):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-13 11:57:54.180: E/AndroidRuntime(23763):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-13 11:57:54.180: E/AndroidRuntime(23763):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**EDIT:**

I was testing my code on an HTC Desire A8181.
After being told that the first code snippet wasn't working on some other devices, I tested on a Samsung Galaxy S2 and on the Emulator.

Results:
When loading from resources, the emulator gave an `OutOfMemoryError`, the Galaxy S2 didn't throw an exception but the returned `Drawable` was null.

So I guess for the time being the only solution is to downsample the image.

Comment: I tried running your code on m emulator and am getting the OutOfMemory error even on the "From Res" method :) What device and/or emulator settings that you use that was able to run it without error?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look at:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html

```
decodeStream (InputStream is, Rect outPadding, BitmapFactory.Options opts)
```

or

```
decodeFile (String pathName, BitmapFactory.Options opts)
```

this way you can load your whole bitmap and show it on screen.

You need to set the correct options.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html

```
inSampleSize
```

I tried it with your code:

```
 BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

 options.inSampleSize = 4;

 Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mUri.getPath(),options);
 Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(Resources.getSystem(),myBitmap);
 updateDrawable(d);
```

works for me.

Comment: As I said in my question, I have no problem loading an Image from resources. In addition I don't want to resize the image.

Comment: sorry I missed that then try the decodeStream (InputStream is, Rect outPadding, BitmapFactory.Options opts) method

Comment: I repeat *I don't want to resize the image*.

Comment: you **need** to scale and tile you cannot hold a bitmap 5000x4000px in memory. to zoom and pan you'll need to figure out what part of the original image would be visible and load the respective tiles scaled to the density of the screen

Comment: btw: the code to load the image from resource will give you a OutOfMemory on a Galaxy Nexus if hardware rendering is enabled

Comment: I never said anything about holding a `Bitmap` in memory. In fact if you read my question, you should notice that I'm using a `Drawable`. I achieve panning and zooming by using `Drawable.setBounds()`. The drawable is created from an InputStream. You can find the full source [here](https://github.com/BenitoBertoli/ZoomImageView/blob/master/src/com/benitobertoli/largeimagezoom/ZoomImageView.java).

Comment: I have the project up and running. The loading by resource does not work on my Galaxy Nexus. But i think the loading by resource does exactly the same thing, scaling the bitmap down to the density of the screen. I think by doing `setBounds()` the drawable get upscaled to fit the region.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, the best option is to split the image into smaller pieces. This will prevent the application to give an OutOfMemoryException. Here is my example code

First get the image from the SD Card an put it into an Bitmap

```
Bitmap b = null;
        try {
            File sd = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + link_to_image.jpg);
            FileInputStream fis;

            fis = new FileInputStream(sd);

            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inPurgeable = true;
            options.inScaled = false;

            b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, options);
            fis.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Split the bitmap (b) into smaller pieces. In this case SPLIT_HEIGHT is 400.

```
double rest = (image_height + SPLIT_HEIGHT);
        int i = 0;
        Bitmap[] imgs = new Bitmap[50];

        do {
            rest -= SPLIT_HEIGHT;
            if (rest < 0) {
                // Do nothing
            } else if (rest < SPLIT_HEIGHT) {
                imgs[i] = Bitmap.createBitmap(b, 0, (i * SPLIT_HEIGHT), image_width, (int) rest);
            } else {
                imgs[i] = Bitmap.createBitmap(b, 0, i * SPLIT_HEIGHT, image_width, SPLIT_HEIGHT);
            }

            i++;

        } while (rest > SPLIT_HEIGHT);
```

Now you have a collection of smaller images. If you want to do it perfecly, you can recycle this bitmap:

```
// Not needed anymore, free up some memory
        if (b != null)
            b.recycle();
```

From this point you can put the smaller images onto the canvas. In my next code I put the images into an ScrollView. The code for putting the images on a Canvas is I think not very different.

```
// Add images to scrollview
        for (int j = 0; j < imgs.length; j++) {
            Bitmap tmp = imgs[j];
            if (tmp != null) {
                // Add to scrollview
                ImageView iv = new ImageView(activity);

                String id = j + "" + articlenumber;
                iv.setId(Integer.parseInt(id));
                iv.setTag(i);

                iv.setImageBitmap(tmp);

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(globalwidth, tmp.getHeight());
                lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, previousLongPageImageId);
                lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);

                container.addView(iv, lp);
                previousLongPageImageId = iv.getId();
            }
        }
```

I hope this will help you.

NOTE: The maximum resolution for images is 2048*2048 (OpenGL restrictions or something), so you will always have to split images into smaller pieces.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Before even trying to split the bitmap `b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, options);` already gives an OutOfMemoryError. In addition, you are splitting the bitmap into 50 smaller ones, yet your are still loading all of them at the same time in memory, which gives the same result.

Comment: If you set android:largeHeap="true" and then do the code above? Like i said in my note, you will have to split the image into pieces because the maximum resolution is 2048*2048. Of course in my solution you will also have to split the image into vertical pieces (width is highter than 2048).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether it is the correct of way of doing this but still this can solve your problem.

Try opening your image in a webview. This will provide you in-built zoom-in/out and panning feature and you dont have to worry about opening any input stream or anything else.

To open an image in webview from assets:

```
    WebView  wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);  
    wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/abc.png");
```

You can [WebSettings](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html) for allowing zoom controls.

Hope this will help you!!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm developing a Custom View with gesture detection and a WebView just isn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

If it worked when you loaded from resources and now it doesn't work when you load manually then I suspect that you have some problem with resource management, probably some memory leak.

Does `OutOfMemoryError` occur always at the start of application or it happens in later time? Is it on configuration change? Do you use static fields (if used incorrectly this often leads to memory leaks in Android application, [example with explanation](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html) this fits to your case)?
Try use some profiling tools ([google](https://www.google.pl/search?q=android%20memory%20leaks) can help to find something useful).

Comment: `OutOfMemoryError` occurs on this line `Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(input, "image");` when I'm loading from Uri. I'm not using any static fields. You can check out the full class [here](https://github.com/BenitoBertoli/ZoomImageView/blob/master/src/com/benitobertoli/largeimagezoom/ZoomImageView.java). I'm calling `setImageUri()`.

Comment: this link is for working code (image loaded from resources). Apparently you didn't push problematic changes (new branch?).

Comment: Please check again now. I added a menu. "From Res" and "From File". The error occurs using "From File". You have to copy `huge_image.png` from `res/drawable` to your sdcard and replace the path in your code.