# I want to make a president review app in Android Studio that has pictures of every president, but I keep getting OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, android-studio, out-of-memory

I have just started Android Studio and am also a little new to java, so please excuse the inefficient code.

Anyway, when I click on the button on the main activity on my app to take the user to the activity that I want to display the images, my app stops working and it throws an OutOfMemoryError.

Here is MainActivty.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button presidentQuizButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.presidentQuizButton);
    Button reviewPresidentsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reviewPresidentsButton);

    presidentQuizButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            //when button is clicked, do something
        }
    });
    reviewPresidentsButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            //when button is clicked, do something
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, presidentReviewActivity.class));
        }
    });

}
```

Here is presidentReviewActivity.java:

```
ImageView imageView;
    public int presidentNumber = 0;

    private Drawable drawable;
    private Drawable [] drawables = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_president_review);

        Button menuButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.menuButton);
        Button nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
        Button backButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backButton);

        drawables = new Drawable[]{
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.president1),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.president2),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.president3),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.president4),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.president5),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.president6),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.president7),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.president8),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.president9),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.president10),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.president11),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.president12),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.president13),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.president14),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.president15),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.president16),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.president17),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.president18),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.president19),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.president20),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.president21),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.president22),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.president23),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.president24),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.president25),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.president26),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.president27),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.president28),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.president29),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.president30),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.president31),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.president32),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.president33),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.president34),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.president35),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.president36),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.president37),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.president38),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.president39),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.president40),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.president41),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.president42),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.president43),
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.president44),
        };

        menuButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                presidentNumber++;
                drawable = drawables[presidentNumber];
                imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
            }
        });
```

And here is most of the error log:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wcphi.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Instead of store all the drawable content in an array. You can actually just store the resource id in a array.

1. replace `private Drawable [] drawables = null;` with `private int[] drawableids`
2. replace `drawables = new Drawable[]{...}` to `drawableids = new int[]{...}`
3. replace

   ```
   drawable = drawables[presidentNumber];
   imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
   ```

to

```
drawable = getResource().getDrawable(drawableids[presidentNumber]);
imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Try to change as above steps and try again.
The nullpointerexception may be caused by you did not init the drawableids array or you are still using the drawables array instead of drawableids.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to open the activity, but when I clicked the next button it crashed again because of a NullPointerException.

Comment: @nrlambert hi, can you show me the exception message?

Comment: @nrlambert hi nrlambert, I have updated the answer, maybe you try to check  your code with the updated code.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I got the OutOfMemoryError exception again. Thanks anyways though!

Comment: @nrlambert hmm, can you screen capture your code and show it?

Comment: @nrlambert how large is your drawable image? if it is really too large, maybe you need to change the way to load it.

Comment: @nrlambert refer to this case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11931742/loading-large-images-without-outofmemoryerror

Comment: yeah all the images are pretty big

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to load large size images directly into memory which causes out of memory exceptions,this issue is discussed in details and a nice solution is given in [developers site](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Comment: Thanks, this seems a little too much for me right now though.